# How to recreate MUI Select value click behavior in react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, react-testing-library

**PROBLEM :**

How to recreate click and select options behavior in MUI SELECT component using react testing library?

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-9ykzww?file=/src/__tests__/select.js)